# Post request using fetch to send image(files) but the files cannot be accesed at the server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, api, fetch-api

I am trying to make a airbnb type website where a host who wants to display his hotel can do so to the users. The host uploads images and other data in a form. The image i will host up using cloudinary(a cloud based hosting service) and display it to the users.

So for right now i want to send the images (along with other data which is mainly text and i know how to deal with that) to the server side.

My current html form code looks like this:

```
<form className="form" method="POST" onSubmit={dealingWithAddListing} encType="multipart/form-data">
            <input
                        onChange={validateFileType}
                        type="file"
                        accept='image/png,image/jpeg'
                        multiple
                        id='image'
                        name='image'
            ></input>
</form>
```

There is a submit type button which fires this function:

```
const dealingWithAddListing = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        var imageFiles = document.getElementById("image")
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        for(const file of imageFiles.files){
          formData.append("image",file)
        }
        for(const [key,value] of formData){
          console.log(`key is ${key}`)
          console.log(`value is ${value}`)
        }
      
        console.log(...formData.entries())
        const response = await fetch("/uploadingImages",{
          method:"POST",
          body: formData
        })
        console.log("the response to formdata is ")
        console.log(response)
}
```

The server side code:

```
router.post("/uploadingImages", async (req,res)=>{
  try{
    console.log(req.files)
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

Now in the console i can see the formdata part working as i have logged it.Even the request is hitting properly. But when i access it req.body gives me {} and req.files gives me undefined.

Comment: What are you using to provide `router`?

Comment: You have to use formidable to parse incoming request. I've done it according to this: https://medium.com/@ShiyaLuo/simple-file-upload-with-express-js-and-formidable-in-node-js-d734d248d615